# scala: default values for function with type parameters; used in partial applied context

Tags: scala

How to specify default values for the type parameter in this context?

```
def increase[T: Numeric](x: T, y: T): T = implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus(x, y)

val inc = increase _
```

Output:

> C:\Sources\scala\main.scala:12: error: could not find implicit for
>   evidence parameter of type Numeric[Nothing]
>           val inc = increase _

Comment: See http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/default-type-parameters-with-implicits-in-scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`increase` has a generic type parameter. When you attempt to resolve the method to a function, it is implicitly trying to lookup the type `T` for which it needs to resolve the method. Since you *haven't specified any type*, it attempts to look up `Numeric[Nothing]` and finds out there is no such implicit available in scope.

What you need is to explicitly specify the type `T` for each resolution:

```
scala> val intInc = increase[Int] _
inc: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>

scala> val doubleInc = increase[Double] _
doubleInc: (Double, Double) => Double = <function2>
```

Comment: So, literally you have to specify default type in this case? Oh .. I see, Looks like obvious answer.  Looks like have to amend question title .. Thanks